# Logic app pricing per operation mean it is cheap if you use it once a year?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

So basically want to use it to ingest data from an email once a year most likely. Email comes in, data gets ingested into my blob storage and that's it. However, when I was initialising the logic app, it said the estimated cost was around £150 a month. The only option I see here that might change the outcome is the publish option, where it says "Workflow" or "Container" as options.

Which one will suit my purpose?

Comment: Nah, you’re not looking at the right metric. The only thing you need to be concerned about is the type of app, make sure it’s **Consumption**, not **Standard**. For what you’re doing and the type of trigger you use, the cost will be nearly (if not) free under consumption. A standard app is a whole different kettle of fish, it’s for more serious projects and will have a dedicated cost month on month.

Answer (score 0):

I do exactly what you describe with emails having a csv attachment sent to a specific outlook account and the logic app works very sporadically. As Skin pointed out in his comment, the cost are close to zero as long as I stick to the consumption plan which bills me for vCores something like currently and in my region 0,2 EUR per hour and less that 0,02 EUR per hour for memory usage. Since my function app runs for less than 10 seconds to do the csv to blob storage job, it can hardly move the needle in terms of billing.